# What are $@ and $< in a Makefile?

Tags: makefile

For example in

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

what do they mean?

Comment: What documentation have you read on `make`?  http://www.makelinux.net/make3/make3-CHP-1-SECT-5.html?  http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/howto_makefiles.html?  Anytthing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$@  The file name of the target. 

$<  The name of the first dependency.
```

For more details: [`Makefile symbol reference`](http://www.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/~mai/files/makeReference.html)

Answer (score 3):

`$@` is the name of the target being built - the program or object file being created.

`$<` is the name of the file that <s>caused it to be rebuilt</s> is the name of the file 'whose existence allowed the inference rule to be chose for the target'.

In the example, you might have:

```
program.o: program.c
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c -o $@ $<
```

In this case, `$@` is 'program.o' and `$<` is 'program.c'.  (The rule must be generating an object file because of the '`-c`' option.)

Beware '$<'; if there was a header that was more recent than the program, '$<' would match that instead - and then the compile line wouldn't work.  As shown, it is safe enough, though.

---

Beta comments about '$<'...

The [POSIX](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html) definition of 'make' says:

> - `$<`
>
>   In an inference rule, the $< macro shall evaluate to the filename whose existence allowed the inference rule to be chosen for the target. In the .DEFAULT rule, the $< macro shall evaluate to the current target name. The meaning of the $< macro shall be otherwise unspecified.
>
>   For example, in the .c.a inference rule, $< represents the prerequisite .c file.

So, in the example I gave, '$<' is technically 'unspecified'.  And, in the correct context,
which would be:

```
.c.o:
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c -o $@ $<
```

Then '$<' is unconditionally 'progname.c' when 'progname.o' is being built.

Some versions of 'make' used to do weird things with it; both GNU Make (3.81) and Solaris 10 make seem to behave sanely.  I'm caught in a time-warp, I suspect.  I used the following makefile:

```
all: x.o

x.o: x.c
        ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c -o $@ $<

x.o: x.h
```

I used '`echo "int main(){return 0;}" > x.c`' and '`echo > x.h`' to create the code.  It didn't matter which file was touched out of 'x.c' and 'x.h'; either way, the compilation was 'correct'.  I have an old make-derivative which was, circa 1992, compatible with Sun MAKE of the time in most respects, that mishandles it.

The 7th Edition UNIX Programmer's Manual says:

> The rule to create a file with suffix *s2* that depends on a similarly named file with suffix *s1* is specified
>   as an entry for the ‘target’ *s1s2*. In such an entry, the special macro $* stands for the target name with
>   suffix deleted, $@ for the full target name, $< for the complete list of prerequisites, and $? for the list
>   of prerequisites that are out of date.

It doesn't say anything about what it means outside that context.  I note that 7th Edition 'make' would list both 'x.c' and 'x.h' for '$<' - but POSIX says that is incorrect.

The SUN "make User's Guide" (Revision A of 16 March 1987) says:

> `$<` The name of the dependency file, as if selected by `make` for use with an implicit rule.

That more or less conforms to what you now see.

---

Oh well, such is life; things change around you.  Sometimes you spot it happening; sometimes you don't.

Comment: This is not correct, $< is the first dependency in the list, not necessarily the one that caused the target to be rebuilt.

Comment: P.S. $? is the list of prerequisites newer than the target (or PHONY), so these are the ones that will cause this target to be remade.

Comment: @Beta: OK - I've fixed things up, I think, with some historical commentary.

Comment: I confess I'd never heard of the POSIX make specs, but experiments (like yours with x.c and x.h) show what's really going on.